# React-native(android) AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradle

After running react-native run-android

I get this

```
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat 
installDebug)...
C:\Users\Dd\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7- 
28.0.0.aar\5f8d067ae17f4050cbc3c86889ab0be8\res\values-v28\values- 
v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not 
found.
```

`c:\react\diagnoseme\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource
android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.`

```
C:\Users\Dd\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\5f8d067ae17f4050cbc3c86889ab0be8\res\values\values.xml:1304:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\Dd\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\5f8d067ae17f4050cbc3c86889ab0be8\res\values\values.xml:1304:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

error: failed linking references.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
```

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
 Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

```
* Try:
```

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

```
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 22s
61 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 60 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

```
Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\react\diagnoseme\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
at buildAndRun (C:\react\diagnoseme\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
at isPackagerRunning.then.result (C:\react\diagnoseme\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I am having the same problem...

Comment: @fnaquira I just updated my android studio and graddle

Answer (score 10):

This is because you're using appcompat-v7-28.0.0 and a mismatched compile SDK version (most likely 27). Either downgrade the libraries to match your SDK or upgrade your SDK to match your libraries.

Comment: I've fixed that already. THANKS. Pls can you help me fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930976/android-react-native-output-error-resource-style-theme-appcompat-light-noac