# Android - React-native: Output: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar not found

Tags: android, react-native

Can anyone help fix this? I have been working on this react-native project, all of a sudden I receive this error when I try to run

Android resource linking failed
  Output:  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.gp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.gp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.gp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.gp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.gp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.gp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
  C:\react\gp\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:105: error: style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar (aka com.gp:attr/windowActionBar)' not found.
  error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Dd.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\ffd21d5284a7af29d2ccd91cde565e5a\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Dd\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\react\gp\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\react\gp\android\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\release\processReleaseResources\out\resources-release.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\react\gp\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processReleaseResources\resources-list-for-resources-release.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\react\gp\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\release\processReleaseResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.gp\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\react\gp\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\release\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.gp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.gp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.
  C:\Users\Dd.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\react-native-0.58.5.aar\2e0dcdd9748c262893e29283ff38db41\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar (aka com.gp:attr/windowActionBar)' not found.

error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\Dd.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\ffd21d5284a7af29d2ccd91cde565e5a\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Dd\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\react\gp\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\react\gp\android\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\release\processReleaseResources\out\resources-release.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\react\gp\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processReleaseResources\resources-list-for-resources-release.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\react\gp\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\release\processReleaseResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.gp\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\react\gp\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\release\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Comment: Do you have a dependency on appcompat? If so, what version?

Comment: You're most likely missing a dependency on appcompat. Can you post your build.gradle with your dependencies?