# Android resource linking failed - AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, react-native, aapt

I am receiving errors when trying to bundle an android release for a react-native project. This project should be converted to AndroidX as a note.

#### Error Messages

When trying to build a release build for Android I receive the following errors:

```
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-vector-icons:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
     /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/5c74eb36d229b35abeeb690f5d3b91a3/appcompat-1.0.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

     /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/5c74eb36d229b35abeeb690f5d3b91a3/appcompat-1.0.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

     /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f54ae08833e39bf2b75fd420ffea65b9/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f54ae08833e39bf2b75fd420ffea65b9/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

#### Root Build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0-alpha1"
    reactNativeVersion = "0.59.9"
  }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         google()
        maven {
          url 'https://maven.google.com/'
          name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url  "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        // React native video - exoplayer missing from google repos, temp fix
        maven {
          url "https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0-alpha1"
    reactNativeVersion = "0.59.9"
  }

subprojects {
  afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
      android {
        compileSdkVersion compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion "$buildToolsVersion"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### App build.gradle file

dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-safe-area-context')
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.3'
  implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
  implementation project(':react-native-video')
    implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
  implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
  implementation project(':react-native-iap')
  implementation project(':react-native-version-check')
  implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
  implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
  implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
  implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
  implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    // react-native-google-signin

    // react-native-fbsdk
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
  implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')

    // RNFirebase required dependencies
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"

    // RNFirebase optional dependencies
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.4"

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.9") {force = true}  // From node_modules

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1'
}
```

#### Research

I have seen some other issues of this being reported such as:
[React-native(android) AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792902/react-nativeandroid-aapt-error-resource-androidattr-dialogcornerradius-not)
https://fincoapps.com/error-resource-androidattr-dialogcornerradius-not-found/.

However, these look to be setup as you'd expect. One issue suggests the subprojects edit that exists in the root build.gradle file, but the same error messages always occur.

#### Edit

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Thu May 07 14:26:41 BST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
android.enableJetifier=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
android.useAndroidX=true
```

React-native info

```
npmPackages:
  react: ^16.7.0 => 16.13.1 
  react-native: 0.59.9 => 0.59.9 
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Comment: can you add `gradle-wrapper.properties` file here

Comment: please add `react-native info` in question

Comment: @MuhammadNuman added requested info

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1:

1. Check what all react native projects are supporting androidX now.

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

Search for androidX in the output. Get all the libraries having androidx.

2. Make a change in `build.gradle` inside android/app

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { 
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
        force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.0.0'        
        force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:18.0.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
    }
}
```

These were the libraries that caused problem in my react native project.
Google maintains all the releases here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_07_2019 . You can choose any other version also. This solution solved issue in my case. Let me know if this helps.

## Solution 2

```
rm -rf android/.gradle
rm -rf .gradle
rm -rf ~/.gradle
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: Thanks, where should the build.gradle file be changed. The root file or the app build.gradle.
Furthermore, where should the configurations.all change be made just at the bottom of the file? Should the implementation lines be removed all kept?

Comment: @StuartM before dependencies {}

Comment: @StuartM if solution 1 do not work then you can try solution 2 in my answer