# I want to use sdk 28 instead of sdk 30, but I get this error when creating apk (I'm new in this stuff, please don't be odd)

Tags: android, sdk

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\murat\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage

> Task :app:processDebugResources
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\faecea335808a370d43ddf9ed7c5a1e9\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml","position":{"startLine":1157,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":83800,"endLine":1168,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":84855}}],"original":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\faecea335808a370d43ddf9ed7c5a1e9\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:1158:5-1169:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d478fd87d264bcbb4cbefc372cdf466b\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":217,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":442}}],"original":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d478fd87d264bcbb4cbefc372cdf466b\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d478fd87d264bcbb4cbefc372cdf466b\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml","position":{"startLine":8,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":447,"endLine":11,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":684}}],"original":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d478fd87d264bcbb4cbefc372cdf466b\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5724419690274871c2fb5f6254f4f3e7\core-1.3.2\res\values\values.xml","position":{"startLine":141,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":8808,"endLine":172,"endColumn":24,"endOffset":10868}}],"original":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5724419690274871c2fb5f6254f4f3e7\core-1.3.2\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5724419690274871c2fb5f6254f4f3e7\core-1.3.2\res\values\values.xml","position":{"startLine":141,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":8808,"endLine":172,"endColumn":24,"endOffset":10868}}],"original":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5724419690274871c2fb5f6254f4f3e7\core-1.3.2\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\faecea335808a370d43ddf9ed7c5a1e9\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml","position":{"startLine":3615,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":230328,"endLine":3619,"endColumn":22,"endOffset":230552}}],"original":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\faecea335808a370d43ddf9ed7c5a1e9\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:3616:5-3620:23: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lineHeight not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\faecea335808a370d43ddf9ed7c5a1e9\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml","position":{"startLine":3620,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":230557,"endLine":3624,"endColumn":22,"endOffset":230760}}],"original":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\faecea335808a370d43ddf9ed7c5a1e9\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:3621:5-3625:23: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lineHeight not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d478fd87d264bcbb4cbefc372cdf466b\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml","position":{"startLine":2770,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":173200,"endLine":2793,"endColumn":24,"endOffset":174397}}],"original":"C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d478fd87d264bcbb4cbefc372cdf466b\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:2771:5-2794:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\murat.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\faecea335808a370d43ddf9ed7c5a1e9\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:1158:5-1169:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found.

```
 C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d478fd87d264bcbb4cbefc372cdf466b\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
     
 C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d478fd87d264bcbb4cbefc372cdf466b\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
     
 C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5724419690274871c2fb5f6254f4f3e7\core-1.3.2\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
     
 C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5724419690274871c2fb5f6254f4f3e7\core-1.3.2\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
     
 C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\faecea335808a370d43ddf9ed7c5a1e9\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:3616:5-3620:23: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lineHeight not found.
     
 C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\faecea335808a370d43ddf9ed7c5a1e9\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:3621:5-3625:23: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lineHeight not found.
     
 C:\Users\murat\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d478fd87d264bcbb4cbefc372cdf466b\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:2771:5-2794:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 30s
21 actionable tasks: 21 executed

Comment: Please add your gradle file.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project

Comment: Are you using react native ? I found these similar questions about react native.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62350094/android-resource-linking-failed-aapt-error-resource-androidattr-dialogcorne

https://cmsdk.com/android/aapt-errors-android-resource-linking-failed.html

Comment: Do you know what  AAPT is? im assuming its not the American Association of Physics Teachers, but i have no idea